# Best Mobile Game Framework for ARPG game with Phonegap?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm going to develop an Action-RPG game like Battleheart in Android platform with Phonegap. I wonder what JS Framework work best for this type of Action-RPG in mobile. I have look for few JS Framework such as ImpactJS, LimeJS, CraftyJS, EaselJS and etc. However, I'm still struggling on which JS Framework I should use for mobile web Action-RPG. Can anyone give me some ideas? I will prefer open-source framework. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I strongly recommend ImpactJS!

I already did a game with it and it worked better than I had thought.
Before that I did a prototype with LimeJS but did have some performance issues.
Just give ImpactJS a try :)